# Geometric multiplicity of eigenvalues of a matrix and its transpose:

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

FULL TEXT:

Consider an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$. We know that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$ as well (as $A$ and $A^T$ have the same characteristic polynomial).

Compare the geometric multiplicities of $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue of $A$ and $A^T$.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you tell us what you have done so far?

Comment: Really I have not gone any further than knowing the algebraic multiplicity is the same (it tells you in the statement)... @Mattos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose $B$ is similar to $A$ and in Jordan canonical form. (It may need to have complex entries, but of course not in the Jordan blocks that correspond to real eigenvalues). Is $B^{\sf T}$ then similar to $A^{\sf T}$?

Comment: oh so the geometric multiplicity is the same as you end up with square matrices but transposed right? So if I had a matrix diagonalized, could I find the eigenvectores of the transposed of that matrix by transposing the diagonalization? Thank you! @Henning

Comment: @paugagopadreny: Yes, that sounds right.

Answer (score 3):

To compare the geometric multiplicities of $A$ and $A^T$ of an eigenvalue $\lambda,$ we have to compare the rank of $A-\lambda I$ and rank of $A^T-\lambda I,$ since $n-rank(A-\lambda I)$ is the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ of $A.$

Now, $(A-\lambda I)^T=A^T-\lambda I$, also matrix has same rank with it's transpose.

Therefore, $rank(A-\lambda I)=rank(A^T-\lambda I).$

Hence, geometric multiplicities of an eigenvalue in $A$ and $A^T$ are same.